# using nextUntil function to toggle specific table row

Tags: jquery

I have this table which contains Events, and on a click on its icon ( an arrow ) I create new rows (called child event ) which are then add under the current row. I want, on a click on the same icon to hide its child event, but only his. Right now, f I click on a new event ( a different row) , it will toggle every hidden row, even if they are not relevent to the current row ...

simply I'm trying to force get some kind of UntilNext but I cant get that function to work, and with the simple loop I'm doing atm it skips the oneEvent but triggers EVERY child row and not the one I want.

```
$('.JSONArrow').on("click", function () {

    var image = $(this);
    var Row = image.closest("tr");

    Row.toggleClass("Opened");

    if (Row.hasClass("Opened")) {

        image.attr("src", "/Images/downArrow.png")

        if (!(Row.hasClass("alreadyOpen"))) {
            var id = image.attr("id");

            $.get("/Home/Child/" + id, function (data) {
                Row.after(data);
                Row.addClass("alreadyOpen");
            });
        }
    } else {
        image.attr("src", "/Images/rightArrow.png");
    }

    var tr = Row.nextAll('tr');

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        var eventClass = $(tr[i]).attr('class');
        if (eventClass == 'ChildEvent')
            $(tr[i]).slideToggle()
        else {
            if (eventClass == 'oneEvent')
                return;
        }
    }
});
```

must be something simple to make nextUntil to work only on child row but I havent manage it so far, according to jquery doc it should be simple like :

```
   var tr = Row.nextUntil('tr',$(".oneEvent"));

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        var eventClass = $(tr[i]).attr('class');
        if (eventClass == 'ChildEvent'){
            $(tr[i]).slideToggle()
        }
    }
```

but I cant make it work. Anyone could point out how to do it, or use another jquery function I dont know about that would select all('tr") that are linked(childEvent) to my Row variable and not the others.

I'm not sure poeple will undestand more with the hthml if you dont know asp or mvc4, but here goes : EDIT ::

```
<div class="TableHolder">
    <table id="mainTable">
        <thead> 
            <tr class="header">

                <th class="iconColumn">Child</th>

                <th>Date </th>
                .... other <th>
                </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.logs)

 </table>
```

and thats the table row per say :

```
     string dynamicClass = "";
if (Model.Parent == null )
{
    dynamicClass = "oneEvent";
}
else 
{  
    dynamicClass = "ChildEvent";
}
```

}

```
  <tr class="@dynamicClass">

      <td class="iconColumn">
        @if (Model.Parent == null )
        {
            <img class="JSONArrow" id="@Model.EventID" src="~/Images/rightArrow.png"/>
        }
    </td>

    <td>@Model.TimeUTC.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy")<br />@Model.TimeUTC.ToString("HH:mm:ss") </td>
    .... other column

</tr>
```

I'll try to simplify what I ment :

you have rows.(Event) when you click on a row(Event), new dynamic rows appears under it (called ChildEvent).

if you click a second time on a row(event), you hide the rows if they exists under him, but only if they are  ChildEvent class.

my current code hides ALL the ChildEvent on the table, I want to hide only those under the (event) clicked.

if the user clicks back on a row(event), it will show the (ChildEvent) if they exists, but only the (childEvent) relevant to the row(event) clicked, and not the ChildEvent of the whole table.

childEvent can only be added under its relevant Event.

re-edit :

```
     row.nextUntil(".oneEvent", ".ChildEvent").slidetoggle();
```

this is what i want, textually : toggle the tr who are under the one I clicked, if they have the ChildEvent class. test until you reach a tr who have the class "oneEvent".

I just cant undestand what parameters go where.

rererereedit :

```
<table>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
</table>
```

ON CLICK :

```
 <table>
  <tr class="oneEvent, Opened, alreadyOpened"></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
</table>
```

click on the same oneEvent

```
 <table>
  <tr class="oneEvent, alreadyOpened"></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
</table>
```

click on a new oneEvent :

```
<table>
  <tr class="oneEvent, alreadyOpened"></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class="oneEvent, Opened, alreadyOpened"></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
</table>
```

click on another new oneEvent

```
<table>
  <tr class="oneEvent, alreadyOpened"></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class="oneEvent, Opened, alreadyOpened"></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
  <tr class="oneEvent, Opened, alreadyOpened"></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
```

click back on an earlier one Event :

```
<table>
  <tr class="oneEvent, alreadyOpened"></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class="oneEvent, Opened, alreadyOpened"></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
  <tr class="oneEvent, alreadyOpened"></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
```

click on the 1st OneEvent :

```
<table>
  <tr class="oneEvent, Opened, alreadyOpened"></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class="oneEvent, Opened, alreadyOpened"></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = true></tr>
  <tr class="oneEvent, alreadyOpened"></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
   <tr class=ChildEvent display = false></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
  <tr class=oneEvent></tr>
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant HTML.  I suspect we could reduce your code to only a few lines if you showed us the actual HTML because it looks like there's a lot of redundancy in your code, but we need to know the exact structure of HTML and classes to know what best to suggest.

Comment: I'm confused by this statement: `"select all('tr") that are direct child of my Row variable and not the others."`  Your `Row` variable is the parent `tr` already.  So, why do you want to select `tr` objects that are children of the current `tr`?  Do you have embedded tables?  Again, can you see why we need to see your HTML?

Comment: I could answer this in a few minutes work if you were actually here to answer questions to make it clearer what you want.

Comment: sorry it was dinner break. I  mean logic child, not html child ( not embed table, just the Row variable calls ChildEvent, which are new rows added under himself.

Comment: In the future, I would suggest that you don't post a question when you can't be around to answer questions about it for an hour.  When you post a question, you should be checking over the next 30 mins to see if people understand what you asked or need help understanding it.  More than 90% of your viewers are going to happen in the first hour.  If the question is not clear in that time window, you will lose most of the chances to get a good answer.  Did my answer below work?

Comment: look, i'm sorry I'm not english and makes a mistake and I'm not as clear as it would be I had written this in french, I'm also sorry I had to get out to lunch, but this isnt a chat, I tried the chat and didnt even receive an acknowledgement there was someone else beside me online.

Comment: The HTML you included doesn't show a `.ChildEvent` object or a `.oneEvent` object so I have no idea where either of those are in your HTML hierarchy.  Please include generated HTML (what the browser sees with View/Source) not your template language.  We need to know what the browser actually sees.

Comment: if have a childEvent object, on the tr class=@dynamicClass" ... the tr class will be either childEvent or oneEvent. I put in a quick render of the html code for each possible scenario, I cant really put it any clearer.

Comment: I answered my own question with what is currently working, but another problem have arise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah.  We have enough HTML to see what you're asking for now!  Here's what I would suggest:

```
$('.JSONArrow').on("click", function () {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    if (row.hasClass("Opened")) {
        // click on an already opened row
        this.src = "/Images/rightArrow.png";
        row.removeClass("Opened");
        // close all following .ChildEvent rows until you get to the next .oneEvent
        row.nextUntil(".oneEvent", ".ChildEvent").slideUp();
    } else {
        // click on a closed row
        this.src = "/Images/downArrow.png";
        row.addClass("Opened");
        // if not previously opened, then add the child HTML
        if (!row.hasClass("alreadyOpened")) {
            $.get("/Home/Child/" + this.id, function(data) {
                row.after(data);
                row.addClass("alreadyOpened");
            });
        } else {
            // show all following .ChildEvent rows until you get to the next .oneEvent
            row.nextUntil(".oneEvent", ".ChildEvent").slideDown();
        }
    }
});
```

You also have to fix your HTML.  You separate class names with a space, not with a comma when you put multiple class names in your HTML.  See here for a working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ZkvgN/

---

Since you seem to be having performance problems, here's a special purpose version of nextUntil that is 3x faster as measured in this jsperf: http://jsperf.com/nextuntilfast

```
jQuery.fn.nextUntilFast = function(untilClass) {
    // for speed reasons, this operates only on the 
    // first DOM object in the jQuery object
    var result = [], cur;
    if (this.length) {
        cur = this[0];
        while (cur = cur.nextSibling) {
            // check elements only
            if (cur.nodeType === 1) {
                if ($(cur).hasClass(untilClass)) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    result.push(cur);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return this.pushStack(result, "nextUntilFast", untilClass);
};
```

You would use it by replacing this:

```
 row.nextUntil(".oneEvent", ".ChildEvent").slideDown();
```

with this:

```
 row.nextUntilFast("oneEvent").slideDown();
```

---

OK, here's my third guess at what you want to hide all `.ChildEvent` objects in the current row.  Since the HTML you included has no `.ChildEvent` objects in it, this is again a guess:

```
Row.find(".ChildEvent").slideToggle();
```

---

Since you haven't included your HTML, it's hard to know exactly how to solve this problem.

After reading your question about 20 times (since you aren't around to answer the clarifying questions), here's my best guess at what you're asking.  If what you want to do with the last block of code in your function is to slideUp any rows that are after where the click was up to and not including a row with `.oneEvent`, then you can do that with this code:

```
 Row.nextUntil(".oneEvent", ".ChildEvent").slideUp();
```

The `.oneEvent` indicates where to stop matching sibling elements.  The `.ChildEvent` is a filter that removes items from the result that don't match that selector.  This will give you all following rows up to (but not including) the row that is `.oneEvent` that are also `.ChildEvent` and it will then slide them up.  If they are already closed, it will leave them closed.  If you really want a toggle, then you can use `.slideToggle()` like your original code did, but I was guessing that what you're really after is collapsing of other rows.

This would be a revised version of your code:

```
$('.JSONArrow').on("click", function () {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    if (row.hasClass("Opened")) {
        this.src = "/Images/rightArrow.png";
        row.removeClass("Opened");
    } else {
        this.src = "/Images/downArrow.png";
        row.addClass("Opened");
        // if not previously opened, then add the child HTML
        if (!row.hasClass("alreadyOpen")) {
            $.get("/Home/Child/" + this.id, function(date) {
                row.after(data);
                row.addClass("alreadyOpen");
            });
        }
    }

    // now close all the following rows up to .oneEvent
    row.nextUntil(".oneEvent", ".ChildEvent").slideUp();
});
```

---

This was my original guess at what you needed help with...

The typical way that a click action is applied to the same region that the click occurred and not all regions in the document is with the following algorithm:

```
$(this).closest("parent container selector").find("target selector").action()
```

You use `.closest()` to find the proper parent container.  You use `.find()` to find objects matching a selector that are in this container.

If you want to apply something to all items in the container, then you select a higher container selector (like perhaps the whole table).  If you want to apply something to just this region, then you pick a container selector for the `.closest()` call that goes up only to your immediate region.  The `.find()` then identifies the targets in whatever region you have selected.  In this way, you can target only child objects of whatever scope you want.

For example, to apply an action to all items that match a selector in the same row as the click occurs, you would do this:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("target selector").action()
```

For more specific code, please add your HTML to your question.  As you have it know, you're asking us to try to figure out what your HTML must be by looking at your code.  That's not easy and sometimes not possible and certainly never leads to the best possible solution.

Comment: this doesnt work, I changed the slideup to slidetoggle, and the child row dont respond ( they dont close or open) I'll add in the html, tough I doubt it'll show you much, since its in asp and build in different layouts

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier - post your HTML.  We can't GUESS any further what problem we're trying to solve.  I'm done trying to GUESS until you show the HTML.

Comment: I added it , 2 second after I tested it. I just took time to test your answer 1st...

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier - I made another guess at the top of my answer.

Comment: hum ... no you were right with your 1st idea, I want a NextUntil().slidetoggle. just the parameters of the nextUntil I cant understand how they works. what you write is exactly whats written in the jquery doc, and its what I understand too, but cant get it to work either way

Comment: OK, finally you have the HTML that we needed to see.  I added another version to the beginning of my answer.

Comment: and its not working, the childEvent tr wont show up when I use your code when you click on the oneEvent tr. but at least I see how your building your nextUntil I'll keep on working with this.

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier - You have errors in your HTML when you have multiple classes that are causing part of the problem.  Only spaces between multiple class names in the HTML no commas.  And, there was a class name error in my suggested code.  I've fixed that.  I also added a working demo.  Please see the beginning of my answer for a block of code that works.

Comment: my html is good in the code, I just put it like that here for speed sake

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier - another point of confusion.  Your code refers to a class `"alreadyOpen"`, but your HTML shows `"alreadyOpened"`.  My code uses `"alreadyOpened"` to match the HTML you presented, but if your HTML in your question is actually wrong, then you will have to modify my code to match the names your use in your exact HTML.  You should be able to se  in the demo page that if you remove all name mismatch errors the code logic works.

Comment: the open and alreadyOpened class are added dynamically when you click on the arrow, you could name them however you want, they are not used anywhere else aside from inside that jquery. The html I wrote it down to show you an exemple, its not actual html, its theres typo error they are just here on the forum, not in the code.

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier - Well, I was trying to make a demo work off the HTML you supplied (that's all I have to test with) and it seriously slowed me down because of the errors you had in that HTML.

Comment: omg, I got what is wrong and why your code never worked ... the $.get function is an ajax-like call to the server, it need data as parameters, not a date

Comment: and I'm still back to where I was, it works, but it still crashes when I try to click on a oneEvent row that have lots of childEvent. The server responds in less than 1 second, and the new rows are added in. but when I click on this again to closed ± 100 childEvent rows, the script crash ...

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier - you will have to supply a link to a working example of your actual page for us to diagnose that type of problem.  What does "script crash" mean?

Comment: I cant supply a link to a working exemple, they are on private server in the France branch of the compagnie I work for. 

the script crash is just that ; a firefox error box pup up, saying that a script have crashed, asking if I want to stop it ( which stops any JS on the page ) or to continue ( which cause the page to freeze and becomes unresponsive)

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier - that's not actually a crash.  That's just an indicator that your script is taking too long to execute.  It needs to be made more efficient.  If I had the actual working HTML that was taking too long, we could analyze what was taking too much time and write that more efficiently.  How many rows do you have in the table?  How many are you trying to collapse at once?  What code are you actually using now that takes too long?

Comment: right now I'm using your latest version of the code. the # of row is dynamically chosen by the user, but not the number of child. the place where the script slows down I have about 50 childEvent visible on screen that are trying to collapse all at once, but even if theres only 4 or 5, you can see it lagging a little bit ( dunno how to describe it better ) , and the "crash" occurs when I try to close the event that have ±50 child, so its the `row.nextUntil(".oneEvent", ".ChildEvent").slideUp()` part that cause it

Comment: Depending upon your exact HTML, you may be able to change the two occurrences of `row.nextUntil(".oneEvent", ".ChildEvent")` to just this `row.nextUntil(".oneEvent")` and skip the filtering step.  There may also be a faster way to do the `nextUntil()` function if that's where the time is going.  But performance is hard to guess when I don't have something to test and measure.

Comment: which seems like it wont be tonight. I'll try that tomorrow morning. thanks alot for all that work done with me

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier - I added a new jQuery method `nextUntilFast()` to my answer that might help you with your performance issue (it's 3x faster).

Comment: Yea, the nextUntilFast is indeed faster (now it doesnt crash 100% of the time, maybe half the time ) but I think the problem is in the number of row, I count them for real and I have more than 800 childEvent associate with that specific oneEvent, I'll try to come up with a way to load them dynamically instead of all at the same time

Comment: @ThierrySavardSaucier - did you try using `.hide()` instead of `.slideToggle()` or `.slideUp()`?  It might be that you can't do that many animations at once.

Comment: yea, I did that this morning since anyway it would not animated anything, and it DID help some more. now with the ajax call made to load only a few childEvent at once I dont have any more problems atm !

Answer (score 0):

Will be easier I guess to keep on working from this instead of my main question who's getting quite clustered ...

```
$('.JSONArrow').on("click", function () {

    var image = $(this);
    var Row = image.closest("tr");

    Row.toggleClass("Opened");

    if (Row.hasClass("Opened")) {

        image.attr("src", "/Images/downArrow.png")

        if (!(Row.hasClass("alreadyOpen"))) {
            var id = image.attr("id");

            $.get("/Home/Child/" + id, function (data) {
                Row.after(data);
                Row.addClass("alreadyOpen");
            });
        }
    } else {
        image.attr("src", "/Images/rightArrow.png");
    }

    Row.nextUntil($(".oneEvent"), $(".ChildEvent")).slideToggle();
});
```

I got it to work like that. but I get a script error which crash my browser when I open a oneEvent tr who have alot of childEvent. the chilldEvent will appear, but after that if I try to click on anything else, I get an error box saying the script have crashed.

Comment: You do NOT pass a jQuery object to nextUntil - you pass selectors.   I've added another revision to my answer.   Please see that.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.6, A DOM node or jQuery object, instead of a selector, may be passed to the .nextUntil() method.

thats what they say, but could it be what cause the crash because it gets too slow to test the jquery so often ?

Comment: It is NOT what you want there.  It would make it a lot, lot slower.  The code I have in my answer now works and just uses selectors.  You also have to fix your class names in your HTML to only have spaces, no commas between them.

Comment: yea, they are correct in my code, I just put a sample html and build it fast not really correctly